# Prevent element wrapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

What is the "best" way or "best practice" to prevent an `HTMLElement` from wrapping ?

I'm actually talking about `relative` positioned elements. I think you could just use `absolute` elements and append those with their `left` position to `anotherElement.width`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YX4cm/

This example uses a `float:left` style, but it also wraps new Elements when there is not enough space on the right side.

So my question here are:

- is there a way to completely deny wrapping ?
- if so, what is the best practice for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use a two-container system, with the inner container set to position absolute so you don't have to actually touch the styles of the inner, repeated elements.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3kB3D/**

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container { width: 200px; background: black; height: 50px; padding: 10px; }
ul { position: absolute; }
li { float: left; margin-right: 12px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `white-space: nowrap` and `display: inline-block` seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/YX4cm/2/

Edit: Works for body as well http://jsfiddle.net/YX4cm/5/

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the element in a container element, which is positioned absolute and has the css property `min-width:[large value]`, as demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/2K5Nz/)